# Filling in space between two parts

Tags: cad, freecad

I'm trying to make a mold of an airfoil, however the airfoil is cambered - I can't simply make rectangular bases and use a cut feature to cut the airfoil out of the mold body. The situation I've arrived at is needing to add material to the undercamber of the airfoil, however it's a very complex shape and I don't have the cad skills to do it.

I've tried using combinations of pads, lofts, etc. I simply can't find a way to fill *only that space* without covering overtop of the leading/trailing edge of the airfoil:

[image: Airfoil mold showing space in undercamber]

The two parts are partDesign Bodies.

How would I fill this space using Freecad?

Comment: Hi Brydon and welcome to SE.3DP...